# Using Top with Union all

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, union-all

In `SQL Server 2014`, I am using the `Northwind` as sample database, and `Orders` table.

For Selecting the First row:

```
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders
```

Output:

```
orderID CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   RequiredDate
10248   VINET   5   1996-07-04 00:00:00.000 1996-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

For Selecting The last row:

```
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders order by orderID desc
```

Output:

```
orderID CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   RequiredDate
11077   RATTC   1   1998-05-06 00:00:00.000 1998-06-03 00:00:00.000
```

Lets combine The First and Last Rows via using `Union ALL`:

```
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders
union all
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders order by orderID desc
```

Output:

```
orderID CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   RequiredDate
10248   VINET   5   1996-07-04 00:00:00.000 1996-08-01 00:00:00.000
10248   VINET   5   1996-07-04 00:00:00.000 1996-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

**So Why the last result doesn't show the data as expected.**

I know for getting the first and last row, use the next one:-

```
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders
union all
Select * from
(
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders order by orderID desc ) a
```

Output:-

```
orderID CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   RequiredDate
10248   VINET   5   1996-07-04 00:00:00.000 1996-08-01 00:00:00.000
11077   RATTC   1   1998-05-06 00:00:00.000 1998-06-03 00:00:00.000
```

But I am still confused why I should but second select into derived table !

Comment: They're different because you aren't using an `ORDER BY` on the first query.  Without an `ORDER BY` the `TOP 1` result is not guaranteed to be the same every time.  If you're wanting to get the first result, you need to do an `ORDER BY orderID ASC`.

Comment: @Siyual, it is not working , if I used `Order by OrderID ASC` in the First query, I am getting: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders
union all
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders order by orderID desc
```

actually works as:

```
(select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders
union all
select top 1 orderID, CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate 
from orders) order by orderID desc
```

Because the order by is evaluated at the very last in a union unless it is wrapped inside a subquery.

You already know the workaround, so I am not mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and this is what I expected, last point is it documented ?